# jodconverter doesn't find soffice.bin

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jetty, jodconverter

I'm trying to use JODConverter on top of jetty and sinatra. Whenever I fire up my Jetty server, which has the sinatra application deployed to it in a war. i get this exception (much cruft removed):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid officeHome: it doesn't contain soffice.bin:
```

in my settings.yml file I have the following:

```
secret: Whatever_you_want_it_to_be
PARAMETER_OFFICE_PORT: 8100
PARAMETER_OFFICE_HOME: /Volumes/OpenOffice.org 3.3/OpenOffice.org.app/Contents/MacOS
PARAMETER_OFFICE_PROFILE: /Applications/OpenOffice.org.app/Contents/MacOS
```

and here are the contents of those last two directories:

```
>ls '/Volumes/OpenOffice.org 3.3/OpenOffice.org.app/Contents/MacOS' 
about.png     crashrep      intro.png     sbase         sdraw         simpress      soffice       sofficerc     testtool      unopkg        urelibs
boot straprc   fundamentalrc resource      scalc         setuprc       smath         soffice.bin   swriter       unoinfo       unopkg.bin    versionrc

>ls /Applications/OpenOffice.org.app/Contents/MacOS                      
about.png     crashrep      intro.png     sbase         sdraw         simpress       soffice       sofficerc     testtool      unopkg        urelibs
bootstraprc   fundamentalrc resource      scalc         setuprc       smath          soffice.bin   swriter       unoinfo       unopkg.bin    versionrc
```

Notice that both ls's show "soffice.bin" in them

update:

I've also tried this:

```
> sudo chmod 777 '/Volumes/OpenOffice.org 3.3/OpenOffice.org.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice.bin'
Password:
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Volumes/OpenOffice.org 3.3/OpenOffice.org.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice.bin: Read-only file system
```

I've also tried using the second directory for office_home and vice versa. no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're either missing a JAR file or there may be a conflict in the JAR files being used.  Although it's not JRuby, this post should shed some light: http://groups.google.com/group/jodconverter/browse_thread/thread/cdf6600288bfba5a/8ed4558cfde08e39

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still has the same problem (as I did) the problem was, that the parameter OfficeHome for Mac has to specify the folder "Contents", not the folder "Contents/MacOs/".

The JODConverter is checking if the following exists:

```
new File(officeHome, "MacOS/soffice.bin")
```

So the OpenOffice home folder should have been **/Applications/OpenOffice.org.app/Contents**.